# OAuth2 breaks security for desktop apps?

Tags: oauth

Currently in the process of moving from OAuth1 to OAuth2 in a desktop application for a web service (Imgur), I've been baffled by the OAuth2 specs. Apparently it breaks all the security OAuth1 provided, according to this doc http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified and by looking at different services docs regarding OAuth2.

With OAuth1 you could use a URL to the service where the user would grant access and a PIN was displayed to copy/paste in your app, which was really nice security in the sense that the user never grants their login/password to the app, and can revoke the given access to it at any time through the service's website.

Now with OAuth2 they left this scenario out, forcing the app to request the user's login/password, unless the app makes their own script in their website to receive a token from the service after granting access (then have the user copy/paste it from your website)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Read [this article](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) from Erin Hammer, its quite illuminating. OAuth2 was a good idea at the start but got incredibly twisted along the way to implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop applications can and should use a user agent (browser) to do OAuth and that is described in the OAuth 2 spec under "Native Applications". The flow you described is meant more for devices with limited input capabilities like a gaming console, printer, camera, etc.

AFAIK, the device flow was in the early specs of OAuth 2, but was omitted at some point. Some API providers like Google have implemented limited support for it regardless.

Comment: Simulating a browser input in a desktop app means giving the app full login credentials however, completely missing the point of using OAuth in the first place (all security is gone). Why is there no PIN method with OA2?

Comment: To be clear, the app should never be directly capturing the user login for the provider. The flow for native applications involves launching a user agent/browser and letting the user interact directly with the authorization server. In other words, you're not simulating, you're delegating to an actual browser that the user installed/trusts.

Comment: Yes, but OAuth2 doesn't provide a copy/paste PIN mechanism, the auth call redirects to a given URL in every possible case, so the app is left out of the flow. The only solution is building your own PIN page the auth would redirect to, which isn't always possible/available, or handling the user's login/password, which removes the security.

Comment: Hikari, that is simply not true. For desktop applications, there are provisions for returning to the app after the user authorizes with the provider in the browser. Not every provider might support it, but for an example of how it can be done refer to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: "The authorization code can be returned to your application in the title bar of the browser or to an http://localhost port in the query string.". This is different from the PIN mechanism in OAuth1. Titlebar = the app must embed a browser page itself, that's bloated/extra complication. localhost: app must act as webserver just to receive the request back. Why couldn't they keep the PIN flow from OA1, that worked great until now.

Comment: Back to your original question, desktop applications *can* use OAuth 2 just fine. There is no need ask the user for a username & password. It is mentioned in the spec & there are providers that support native/desktop apps.  Maybe you don't like the way they did it, but they didn't ignore the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Native applications are the way to go. See the ["Native Applications"][1] section of OAuth 2.0 RFC. The native applications are not intended to store passwords. If you want to avoid entering of credentials directly in the app (even within a browser control), you may do the following from the OAuth 2.0 native application:

1. Launch the default browser with the authorization endpoint.
2. Implement a simple web page for your redirect URI, which picks the authorization code and shows it to the user.
3. Ask the user to copy the code and paste it back in the native application.

Alternatively, the spec suggests that you leverage the URL redirection scheme of the native platform to bring back the original application. You may check iOS and Android's "URL Scheme" capabilities. Unfortunately, neither of these platforms guarantees uniqueness of the URL scheme, hence the authorization code  may be hijacked by another rogue app, which is activated on the same URL. I have filed an iOS bug for that.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-52